# How to specify custom id or attributes in vite.config.js for iife

Tags: vite

I am building a react app using `iife` format, so that the whole app is in one javascript that I can reference from index.html script.

The `vite.config.ts` is like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite"
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc"

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: Number(process.env.PORT) || 3000
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        format: "iife",
        name: "foo",
        assetFileNames: "[name][extname]",
        entryFileNames: "foo.js",
        chunkFileNames: "foo.js",
        extend: true,
        sourcemap: false
      }
    }
  }
})
```

It when building with `npm run build` it generates the `dist` folder with and index.html which has

```
<script type="module" crossorigin src="/foo.js"></script>
```

I want vite to generate something like

```
<script id="my-custom-id" type="module" crossorigin src="/foo.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script id="my-custom-id" type="module" crossorigin src="/foo.js" data-foo="one" data-bar="two"></script>
```

with id and/or custom attributes.

I cannot find anything in documentation nor googling, and hopefully there is a way?

Comment: did you find a way to do tath ?

Comment: @ehsanwwe no, I went with a different approach in the end